# Claims based authorization with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity

I was reading up a lot of blog posts and stackoverflow answers but still I am unable to find a real world open source project which uses claims based authentication and authorization, so that I can get an idea on how to actually implement these.

So far what I could find is [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/) and [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2010/02/05/137795.aspx) implements a claims based authorization on a sample website. If you guys could point me some Open source projects using claims, that would be really helpful.

What I am interested is how to retrieve claims for my application using the database.

So far, what I have tried is that using an in memory claims store to simulate the databsae, I have created a `CustomClaimsTransformer` and `CustomAuthorisationManager` like this.

```
public class CustomClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
    {
        public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
        {
            //validate name claim
            string nameClaimValue = incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name;

            return CreatePrincipal(nameClaimValue);
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal CreatePrincipal(string userName)
        {
            int userId = ClaimStore.Users.First(u => u.Value == userName).Key;
            var claims = ClaimStore.ClaimsSet.Where(c => c.Key == userId);

            var claimsCollection = claims.Select(kp => kp.Value).ToList();

            return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsCollection, "Custom"));
        }
    }

public class CustomAuthorisationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    { 
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            string resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
            string action = context.Action.First().Value;

            if (action == "Show" && resource == "Code")
            {
                bool likesJava = context.Principal.HasClaim(ClaimStore._httpMyclaimsUsers, "True");
                return likesJava;
            }
            else if (action == "Read" && resource == "Departments")
            {
                bool readDeps = context.Principal.HasClaim(ClaimStore._httpMyclaimsDepartments, "Read");
                return readDeps;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How to implement these in a real world scenario without having too many IF conditions?

Comment: how did you end up doing it? can you please provide an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to design my own system with the required functionality using the existing asp.net identity 2.0 tables + a few of my own.

I'm gonna call every AREA-CONTROLLER-ACTION trio as resources in my system. WebAPI included. Area itself is a resource. Controller itself is a resource. Action itself is a resource. Any combination of them, is also a resource. I'll auto generate everything from the system itself using reflection.

Also, I'm going to use the same `AspNetRoles` table to store my User Groups. Users belong to one or more groups (Super Admin, Admin, Agent, Client etc.).

Using the existing Role based model as a user group based model with claims, I could get it working.Super admins are on god mode. They can create lower level users/groups/assign permissions etc.

Users can have special permissions. For example, Everyone in Agent group is denied access to updating a hotel, but a special agent who might also be the owner of a hotel can be given specific access to updating only their hotel.

Since the entire access control system runs on MVC area-controller-action sets. No one initially has no access (including super admins) and we gradually define which parts the groups/users has access to. And we give super admins and admins exclusive access through a claim. Access to everywhere is denied by default.

Once I Auto generated the AREA-CONTROLLER-ACTION sets, I let the user select which group has access to which item.

When the user logs in, I get all the resources the current user has access to and store them as claims. Based on that, using a claims auth manager, when a user request access to some resource, I can check their claims and decide if they should be given access to.

```
foreach(var claim in permissionClaims) {
    var parts = claim.Value.Split(new [] {
        '|'
    }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (parts.Length == 3) {
        //var httpMethod = parts[0];
        var action = parts[1]; 
        var api = parts[2];
        //Current.Log.Warn("Checking Access : " + req + " [action: " + action + "]");
        // is this request for a API action?
        if (api.Contains("API")) {
            // if so, req must be for a API action
            if (req.Contains("Api") && action.Contains(req)) {
                Log.Trace("User has access to API : " + req + " [action: " + action + "]");
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            // this is for a MVC action
            if (action.Contains(req)) {
                Log.Trace("User has access to MVC : " + req + " [action: " + action + "]");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have explained the approach in detail [here - ASP.NET MVC Fine Grained Identity & Access Control](http://blog.dinklabs.com/2015/11/mvc-fine-grained-identity-access-control-1.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following link , it seems like a decent solution

http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/custom-claims-based-authorization-in-net-using-axiomatics-pep-sdk-for-net.html

Also you can define your policy and load it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.loadcustomconfiguration.aspx

How to: Implement Claims Authorization in a Claims-Aware ASP.NET Application Using WIF and ACS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185907.aspx

Comment: Thank you for these valuable resources. I have looked into each and Axiomatics SDK sounds promising but I don't use it. Looks like I will have to go with a custom implementation with policies defined in the web.config or the database. I just don't understand how to evaluate rules.

Comment: (disclaimer - I work for Axiomatics) Going for a custom implementation is never a good way to go. There are plenty of frameworks out there that cater to a range of authorization - from simple to complex. Microsoft even has built-in claims-based authZ. Implementing your own is definitely not the way to go